# mongoid filter is not returning the same result as the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongoid

When I tried querying my db with Mongoid, it's not returning the same result as when I do it within the mongo shell.  With mongo shell, when I do

```
db.scenarios.find({"test_run_id": 169926}).count()
```

I get 214 as a result.  When I tried the following mongoid statement:

```
Scenario.where({'test_run_id' => 169926}).to_a.count
```

I get 0 as a result.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database in both cases?

Comment: yes, when I do Scenario.all().count the result is the same when I do db.scenarios.find().count()

Comment: Have you checked the Moped logs to see what query Mongoid is sending to MongoDB? Have you tried `Scenario.collection.find(:test_run_id => 169926)` to see what that says?

Comment: figured out what the problem is.  It's because my model file has the test_run_id defined as a String when it should be an integer.

Comment: You might want to put that down as an answer.

Comment: Remove to_a, Scenario.where({'test_run_id' => 169926}).count or Scenario.where({'test_run_id' => 169926}).size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my model.rb file specified test_run_id as type String when it should be Integer.  So when the filter is executed, "169926" != 169926, therefore no match was found.  The lesson here is that make sure the data type matches between your model.rb and what is actually stored.